# Mapping/crosswalk between SIC to GICS industry classification systems

Tags: market-data, sec

Is anyone aware of a public SIC to GICS industry classification crosswalk?

I am aware of a mapping/crosswalk for:

- [SIC to NAICS](https://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/concordances/concordances.html)
- [ISIC to NAICS](https://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/concordances/concordances.html)

Comment: This does not actually answer your question, but this may be useful to you: https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/det_48_ind_port.html

Comment: Related question: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/66552

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since GICS is owned by S&P, the mapping is not public information and as such finding a public mapping is difficult. On the other hand, [emailing S&P works for existing customers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437669/gics-to-naics-crosswalk?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

It costs money https://classification.codes/store/selection/?from_id=81&to_id=116 in euros, not in dollars