# Finer classification of stocks beyond sector/industry

Tags: equities

There are classifications of stock in sector/industry. But such classifications are rather coarse.

https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/markets_sectors/sectors/sectors_in_market.jhtml

Stocks in an industry can be further classified. For example, in cybersecurity, there are the following stocks.

https://www.fool.com/investing/stock-market/market-sectors/information-technology/cybersecurity-stocks/

Is there a centralized database with a finer classification of all stocks?

Answer (score 2):

There are many taxonomies, not very different from one another, all of which start with 10-12 sectors, and further divide them into industries and subindustries. Some popular industry classifications are:

Global Industry Classification Standard (GICS) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_Standard , [MSCI document](https://www.msci.com/documents/1296102/11185224/GICS+Methodology+2020.pdf)  - developed by Morgan Stanley Capital International (MSCI) and Standard & Poor's (S&P) in 1999. S&P tries to assign every public company to a GICS industry. My subjective impression is that GICS is the most often used in practice.

Industry Classification Benchmark (ICB) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Classification_Benchmark - created by Dow Jones and FTSE in 2005. Used by NYSE, NASDAQ, and many other stock exchanges.

The Refinitiv Business Classification (TRBC) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Refinitiv_Business_Classification is the Reuters industry classification that was rebranded when Reuers spun off Refinitiv.

North American Industry Classification System (NAICS) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Industry_Classification_System is better suited for classifying activities within a company, although many people mis-use it to classify entire companies.

International Standard Industrial Classification of All Economic Activities (ISIC)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Industrial_Classification is the United Nations taxonomy. Like NAICS, it is better suited for activities than for entire companies.

If you have access to a Bloomberg terminal or Eikon, then you should have no trouble getting multiple classifications for all the stocks you're considering. However you may decide that you don't like any available classification because none are granular enough for whatever your needs are, and you may choose to override some classifications with your own.

Comment: Just to be sure. None of the classifications that you mentioned covered at the level of cybersecurity in my post as an example?

Comment: right - nowhere close! My point is, "standard" taxonomies don't go into this level of detail.